# Bootstrap 3 DataTable export to Excel not exporting table data

Tags: java, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to export the contents of a table to MS Excel using this example: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

I have everything displaying correctly on the page; however, when I export I only get the title and column headings. I am generating the table contents in java.

Page image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Output:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
***Second Attempt***

I have changed my approach and am now passing json. However, now the buttons are not displaying and the table is not formatted. No errors in the console log.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
***Third Attempt***

OK I have worked out how to pass the JSON and use AJAX to populate the table. However, the export to Excel still only exports the name and table headings.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
***Fourth Attempt***

I am trying:

```
$('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
   "ajax": responseJson1a,
} );
```

I also tried:

```
$('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
   "ajax": JSON.stringify(responseJson1a),
} );
```

And I have cleaned up the libraries.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Group Summary</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
        <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Validate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Le styles -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>

  <body>

    <div id="groupSummary"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showGroupSummaryForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <h3>Group Summary</h3>

                            <div class="container">

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                            <input type='text' id="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button id='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Display Details</button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="container" id=joined>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <table id="joinedTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th>section</th>
                                              <th>subSection</th>
                                              <th>metric</th>
                                              <th>metricTotal</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </table>
                                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                                        <span id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse1" style="color: red;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /container -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/groupSummary-ajax.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

//  $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
//      "paging":   false,
//        "ordering": false,
//        "info":     false,
//        "searching": false,
//        dom: 'Bfrtip',
//        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
//    } );



    $("#showGroupSummaryForm").validate({
        //debug: true,

        rules: {
            startDate: {
                required: true
            },

            endDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            startDate: {
                required: "Please select a start date."
            },

            endDate: {
                required: "Please select an end date."
            }
        },

        submitHandler : function(showGroupSummaryForm) {

            $('#joinedTable tbody > tr').remove();
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

            var dataToBeSent  = {
                    ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                    startDate : $("#startDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#endDate").val()
            };

            //Joined
            $.ajax({
                url : 'GroupSummaryJoinedView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data : dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',  
            })
            .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No members joined in this date range')){
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('No members joined in this date range.');
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('Error getting joined data.');

                }
                $("#datepicker1").focus();
            })
            .done(function(responseJson1a){
                dataType: "json";
//              alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a)); 
//              Result of alert is:
//                  [{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Explorer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Pioneer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":8},{"section":"Joey","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Leader","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Rover","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Scout","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":2}]
                $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
                    "ajax": responseJson1a,
                } );

            })
        }
    })

}); // end document.ready

$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            });
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });
    $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker2').data("DatePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker1').data("DatePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

This gives me an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (groupSummary-ajax.js:70)
    at i (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:27449)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:28213)
    at y (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:4:22721)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:4:26925)
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
***Narrow down the error***

The error is not due to the HTML table being populated from JSON. The "$('#joinedTable').DataTable();" being in the ".done(function(responseJson1a)" causes the error. The below works until the "$('#joinedTable').DataTable();" is un-commented. However, only the

```
<tr>
   <td>Cubs</td>
   <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Scouts</td>
   <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

is exported. Not

```
<tr>
   <td>Cubs</td>
   <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Scouts</td>
   <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Group Summary</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
        <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Validate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Le styles -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>

  <body>

    <div id="groupSummary"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showGroupSummaryForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <h3>Group Summary</h3>

                            <div class="container">

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                            <input type='text' id="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button id='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Display Details</button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="container" id=joined>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="joinedTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th>Section</th>
                                              <th>Joined</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                            <tbody id="mytablebody">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Cubs</td>
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td>Scouts</td>
                                                    <td>5</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                        <!--<tbody id="mytablebody"></tbody> -->
                                    </table>
                                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                                        <span id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse1" style="color: red;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /container -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/DataTable.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

    $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
    } );



    $("#showGroupSummaryForm").validate({
        //debug: true,

        rules: {
            startDate: {
                required: true
            },

            endDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            startDate: {
                required: "Please select a start date."
            },

            endDate: {
                required: "Please select an end date."
            }
        },

        submitHandler : function(showGroupSummaryForm) {

            $('#joinedTable tbody > tr').remove();
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

            var dataToBeSent  = {
                    ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                    startDate : $("#startDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#endDate").val()
            };

            //Joined
            $.ajax({
                url : 'GroupSummaryJoinedView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data : dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',  
            })
            .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No members joined in this date range')){
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('No members joined in this date range.');
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('Error getting joined data.');

                }
                $("#datepicker1").focus();
            })
            .done(function(responseJson1a){
                dataType: "json";

//              alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a)); 
//              Result of alert is:
//                  [{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Explorer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Pioneer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":8},{"section":"Joey","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Leader","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Rover","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Scout","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":2}]

                 var tablebody2 = '          <tr>' + 
                    '<td>Cubs</td>' +
                    '<td>9</td>' +
                  '</tr>' +
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Scouts</td>' +
                    '<td>10</td>' +
                  '</tr>';

                 $("#mytablebody").empty();
                 $("#mytablebody").append(tablebody2);
//               $('#joinedTable').DataTable(); // Uncomment this and the error happens
            })
        }
    })

}); // end document.ready

$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            });
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });
    $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker2').data("DatePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker1').data("DatePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the `dataTable` before the table gets populated, that's why it can't see any of the dynamic data you are fetching via `ajax`. Put the initialization code after the data table has been rendered (see `-- INIT --` below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    // push the init code 

    $("#showGroupSummaryForm").validate({
        //debug: true,

        rules: {
            startDate: {
                required: true
            },

            endDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            startDate: {
                required: "Please select a start date."
            },

            endDate: {
                required: "Please select an end date."
            }
        },

        submitHandler : function(showGroupSummaryForm) {

            $('#joinedTable tbody > tr').remove();
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

            var dataToBeSent  = {
                    ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                    startDate : $("#startDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#endDate").val()
            };

            //Joined
            $.ajax({
                url : 'GroupSummaryJoinedView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data : dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
            })
            .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No members joined in this date range')){
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('No members joined in this date range.');
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('Error getting joined data.');

                }
                $("#datepicker1").focus();
            })
            .done(function(responseJson1a){
                // JSON response to populate the joined table
                populateTable(responseJson1a)

                // -- INIT -- 
                // initialize the table
                // after the data has loaded
                $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
                    serverSide: true,
                    initComplete : function () {
                    table.buttons().container()
                       .appendTo( $('#joinedSpace .col-sm-6:eq(0)'));
                    },
                });
            })
        }
    });
}); // end document.ready

function populateTable(object) {

    var obj = object;
    var table = $("<table id='joinedTable'/>");
    table[0].border = "1";
    var columns = Object.keys(obj[0]);
    var columnCount = columns.length;
    var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = $("<th />");
        headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
        row.append(headerCell);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
        for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            var cell = $("<td />");
            cell.html(obj[i][columns[j]]);
            row.append(cell);
        }
    }

    var dvTable = $("#joinedSpace");
//    dvTable.html("");
    dvTable.append(table);
}

$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("MenuGL.html");

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            });
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });
    $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker2').data("DatePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker1').data("DatePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Another alternative that saves you from populating the table yourself, is to pass the `url` to the JSON feed directly to the `dataTable` plugin and let the table handle the `ajax` and the data population. The Controller has to return the data in the format specified [`here`](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

```
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'pathToYourController',
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response; greatly appreciated. Unfortunately this did not work - no change the the current actions. I placed the jQuery just after the DataTable. I tried both "change" and "keypress paste". Please not that I have updated the image as the "Export" button does nothing and may be a red herring. I have reviewed the Column Renderer and find it hard to understand. I am not a programmer and am doing this free for my organisation. Am I creating the table correctly or should it be done differently? A monkey see, monkey do example would be appreciated.

Comment: @Glyn Great job on the app! Keep it up. I've updated my answer to add a few debugging steps, try those and hopefully you should see the text changing. I don't know why the export button is not working but it might be an indicator of javascript breaking somewhere, open your javascript console on your browser and it should tell you all the errors that occurred, if you are using chrome, you can  follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I had someone show me how to use the console so I use that religiously now. When they showed me I found a copious number of errors I was able to fix. There are no errors now. I think I am doing this all wrong and am investigating returning just the values from the java read of the database using JSON rather than the HTML and then using javascript to build the table. Is that how you would do it?

Comment: @Glyn passing the data in JSON and letting the table handle it, saves you from writing html. That and letting the dataTable handle the inputs fields is probably a cleaner approach. I'll try to concoct something in that mindset I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have figured out how to build each table data row from JSON; however, the export to Excel still does not pick up the data (just the name and column headers).

Comment: @Glyn You just need to initialize the `dataTable` plugin after you populate the data for the plugin to "see" the data. Please see my updated answer. Hopefully this will put a lid on this issue.

Comment: The first solution returned an error on "$('#joinedTable').DataTable( {" -  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (groupSummary-ajax.js:98)
    at i (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:27449)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:28213)
    at y (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:4:22721)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:4:26925)  I will try the second solution. Very much appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Glyn that's strange, maybe I misplaced a curly brace but I think the second approach might be a little better since you let the plugin do everything. I tried their example of my computer and it worked great so fingers crossed it will work for you. I'm 99.9% sure that the reason the fields are not being exported is because of the plugin being initialized prior to inserting the data. Side note, you are using a rather old version of jQuery and you can get an single bootstrap.js file without getting all plugins individually. Just get it to work and then worry about cleanup later.

Comment: Hi again, I have spent the entire day trying many variations. I am also sure that the reason the fields are not being exported is because of the plugin being initialised prior to inserting the data. I have tried: $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
                 "ajax": responseJson1a,
             } );  and $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
                 "ajax": (JSON.stringify(responseJson1a)),
             } );      I still get the error above.

Comment: I have cleaned up the plugins. In the past when I used 3.3.1 I got a conflict error with bootstrap requiring greater than 1.1 and less than 3. In my general cleanup I must have fixed this somehow. I have put the new files above.

Comment: @Glyn do you have [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) installed on your computer? If no, please go ahead and install it, you can use this tool to submit POST requests to your servlet and make verify that it's sending back the data in the right format. The next step will be to take the ajax example from data tables verbatim and get that to work. Then slowly start adding the rest of the features you have one by one.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed Postman. I am having trouble using it. I have displayed the results of JSON that is returned. Is that not the same? I will start back at the very beginning.

Comment: I have found that the error only occurs when the "$('#joinedTable').DataTable();" being in the ".done(function(responseJson1a)" causes the error. Please see the latest edit above.

Comment: @Glyn you are passing the response data to the `ajax` property, you need to pass the `url` to your servlet. Can you strip anything anything important from your project and share it on [Github](https://github.com/), I'll be glad to take a look at it and try help you out.

Comment: Hi, I think I prefer to use build previous method, not the original (that was definitely awful). Either way, the issue is with the "$('#joinedTable').DataTable();" being in the ".done(function(responseJson1a)". Any method I use will need this to be fixed. I use BitBucket as that provides me with the ability to share with five people for free. I set this up, with a lot of stress and trail and error, when someone else said they would help me. Unfortunately it turned out they are to busy. What information can you give me to invite you to the project in BitBucket please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173309/discussion-between-glyn-and-staticbeagle).

Answer (score 1):

The resolution main points are:

```
var table = $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {

table.clear();
table.rows.add(responseJson1a).draw();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Group Summary</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A Scout award tracking application">
        <meta name="author" content="Glyndwr (Wirrin) Bartlett">

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Validate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Le styles -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    </head>

  <body>

    <div id="groupSummary"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

        <div id="includedContent"></div>

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="showGroupSummaryForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <h3>Group Summary</h3>

                            <div class="container">

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                                            <input type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
                                            <input type='text' id="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button id='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Display Details</button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="container" id=joined>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="joinedTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th>Section</th>
                                              <th>Joined</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="mytablebody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                                        <span id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse1" style="color: red;"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /container -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/DataTable.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

    var table = $('#joinedTable').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
        columns: [
                  {data: 'section'},
                  {data: 'metricTotal'}
                  ]
    } );



    $("#showGroupSummaryForm").validate({
        //debug: true,

        rules: {
            startDate: {
                required: true
            },

            endDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            startDate: {
                required: "Please select a start date."
            },

            endDate: {
                required: "Please select an end date."
            }
        },

        submitHandler : function(showGroupSummaryForm) {

            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('');

            var dataToBeSent  = {
                    ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                    startDate : $("#startDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#endDate").val()
            };

            //Joined
            $.ajax({
                url : 'GroupSummaryJoinedView', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data : dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',  
            })
            .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                if(jqXHR.responseText.includes('No members joined in this date range')){
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('No members joined in this date range.');
                }else{
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse1').text('Error getting joined data.');

                }
                $("#startDate").focus();
            })
            .done(function(responseJson1a){
                dataType: "json";

//              alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson1a)); 
//              Result of alert is:
//                  [{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Explorer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Cub","subSection":"Pioneer","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":8},{"section":"Joey","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Leader","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":5},{"section":"Rover","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":1},{"section":"Scout","subSection":"blank","metric":"Joined","metricTotal":2}]

                 table.clear();
                 table.rows.add(responseJson1a).draw();
            })
        }
    })

}); // end document.ready

$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("Menu.html");

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            });
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });
    $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker2').data("DatePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datepicker1').data("DatePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you got it to work. I completely forgot about using `add()`.